# passing a parameter before calling a reload $state angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

what i am excatly doing that at first i am calling the overview from son

```
var accountstate = $myapplication.findOverviewInjector().get("$state");
accountstate.reload();
```

the result is that i am going back to my father page": Entity/account/Details/"

However there is no id at end in the result so i am getting an empty page
my question how can i pass the id to the next page $stateParams?
or how to reload correctly ?
in addtion when i call $state.reload() so i am reloading the child or 
when i am trying

```
$state.reload(accountstate.current,{id:myid.id});
```

so it is could not reload from child to father cause in my home i have two state

also i tried

```
accountstate.reload({id:myid.id});
```

and it does not work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$state.go($state.current, {id: myid.id}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: my friend i need to refresh the father so even when go work so it does not refresh the data and $state.go it would not work ;)